# Unable to redirect after setting cookies in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have form which the users can fill to set their preferences. After they click a button I set cookies and then redirect. This is my code:

```
function allCookie() {
  var slvals = [];
  $('input:checkbox[name=checks]:checked').each(function() {
    slvals.push($(this).val());
  });
  document.cookie = document.getElementById('user').value + '=' + slvals + '; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2030 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.website.com';
  document.cookie = '8MUC=' + document.getElementById('user').value + '; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2030 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.website.com';
  window.location.href='http://www.website.com/';
}
```

Redirect occurs only if I have not filled out any of the form elements.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: `window.location.replace("http://www.website.com/");` try this.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan No there is no error in the console and using the alternative did not work either.

Comment: btw it works on my end.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating your checkbox values into a single string instead of putting them into an array.  Then you can add that string to the final cookie value.

```
var slvals = '';
$('input:checkbox[name=checks]:checked').each(function() {
  slvals = slvals + this.val();
});
```